# Select all records that are not wednesday and are only 30 days old

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how do I query a database to select all records that don't fall in a particular day. In this case, I want to select all records that are not wednesdays. My date column in MySQL database is "Date" ex. 2012-09-10.

My "pseudo" select is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date NOT IN(SELECT* FROM mytable WHERE date = WED)
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the WEEKDAY() function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

2 = Wednesday

```
select *
from mytable
where date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY and
      WEEKDAY(date) <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`select * from mytable where dayofweek(date)!=4;`